# Auto Submitted form does not carry form variables

Tags: php, javascript, html

The following form does not carry form variables when it is submitted using quto javascript after 5 seconds.

Normal submission works fine.

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
setTimeout('document.test.submit()',5000);
//--></SCRIPT>

</head>
<body>
<form name="test" id="form1" method="post" action="auto2.php">
  <p>
    <INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="test" VALUE="option1"> Option1
    <INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="test" VALUE="option2"> Option2
    <INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="test" VALUE="option3"> Option3   
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit_test" value="Submit_test" />
&nbsp;  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
---------------------------------------------------------------

output page:

--------------------------------------------------------------
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit_test'])){
$variable=$_POST['test'];

echo $variable;

}

?>
```

---

Any help is highly appreciated.. thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code of the form and how it's submitted.

Comment: Maybe the user simply didn't have time to check one of the check boxes?

Comment: I have just edited it again. It is now visible.

Comment: @Pekka, even if I have a hidden element, it does not carry over to the output page.

Comment: When in doubt, `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: @Tomcat
var-dump for auto submission is blank, just nothing.
By clicking the button we get the following.
option2

array
  'test' => string 'option2' (length=7)
  'submit_test' => string 'Submit_test' (length=11)

Comment: put the `var_dump` outside your if statement if you had it inside.

Comment: Excellent, now it is visible. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing whether the `submit_test` button value is set:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_test'])){
```

Submitting the form automatically won't set the value, so your test fails.

You should test for some other form field, like a hidden element.

Comment: Tried using a hidden element. No Change, the form works absolutely fine when I click the submit button.. but not when it is auto submitted using Javascript code.
Thank you for trying.

Comment: @Chinnappa no, your *test* doesn't trigger. Try removing it. It'll work.

Comment: Thank you Nalum and Pekka for being patient with me, it took a while for me understand.
I have a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless a checkbox is checked, you wont get any response (blank or otherwise)

What you should have instead is

```
<input type=hidden name="test" value="">
<INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="test" VALUE="option1"> Option1
<INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="test" VALUE="option2"> Option2
<INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="test" VALUE="option3"> Option3
```

That way you get a default value when you post your form

Comment: Added a hidden form field as below:
<input type=hidden name="test1" value="test_value">
output is still blank. var_dump shows nothing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Pekka's answer.

If you do the following it will check to see that the page was posted to without requiring that a variable was set in the post.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ... }
```

You should probably also put in some form of validation to make sure it came from where you expected it to.